# Tell which rows are distinct while keeping the ID variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble with more than 1,000 columns and hundreds of thousands of rows. I'd like to get rid of duplicate values while keeping the unique ID value for each row. Here's a simplified version of what I've tried using mtcars.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  distinct(mpg:carb, .keep_all = TRUE)

#Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
#  Column `mpg:carb` must be length 32 (the number of rows) or one, not 18
#In addition: Warning messages:
#1: In mpg:carb : numerical expression has 32 elements: only the first used
#2: In mpg:carb : numerical expression has 32 elements: only the first used
```

Any ideas how to drop non-unique rows while keeping the ID variable? In the mtcars example, the ID variable is `rownames`. There are too many columns for me to type each one separately.

Comment: As an aside, I'm not even sure mtcars has any duplicates... In the future, try working with a simpler example, e.g.: `dd<-data.frame(a=c("a","b","c","d","e","f"), b=c(1,1:5), c=c(1,1,3,2,4,5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df_filtered<-df[!duplicated(df[,-1]),]
```

(this assumes the ID column is the first one).
What it does is gives you a subset of your dataframe (`df`) that only contains those rows where the entire row except for the first column is not a duplicate of a previous row.